# What is dynamic dispatch and duck typing?

Tags: python, pycharm, terminology

When using Pycharm, It often points out an error, saying:

> Unresolved reference 'name'. This inspection detects names that should
>   resolve but don't. *Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing*, this is
>   possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and
>   class-level items are supported better than instance items.

I've snooped around about this, but most questions and information I find is about preventing the message from being shown. what I want to know is:

- What is dynamic dispatch/duck typing?
- What are (or an example of) these "useful number of cases"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python uses a duck typing convention. This means that you do not have to specify what type a name is. Unlike in Java, for example, where you must specify explicitly that variable may be type `int` or `Object`. Essentially, type checking is done at runtime.

"If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck."

In Python everything will seem to work until you use try to manipulate an object in a way that it is not designed to. Basically, an object may not have a certain method or attribute that another might, and you won't find this out until Python throws an error upon trying it.

Dynamic Dispatch is the practice of the compiler or environment choosing which version of a polymorphic function to use at runtime. If you have multiple implementations of a method, you can use them in different ways despite the methods having the same or similar properties/attributes. Here's an example:

```
class Foo:
   def flush():
       pass

class Bar:
    def flush():
       pass
```

Both classes have a `flush()` method but the correct name is chosen at runtime.

Python is not the best example of this process since methods can take multiple parameters and don't have to be reimplemented. Java is a better example, but I'm not fluent enough in it to provide a correct example.

Comment: Duck typing goes beyond type checking, in some sense. The type doesn't matter *at all*, as long as it provides the correct behavior. If a function expects an argument to have a `foo` method, then that argument can have any type at all, as long as it provides `foo`. It doesn't, for example, have to have a particular `foo`-providing ancestor. True run-time type checking would enforce the argument's type when the function was first called, not when the argument was first used in the body of the function.

Answer (score 4):

The warning means that you're using a variable that PyCharm doesn't recognise, but due to Python's dynamic nature it can't be sure if it's right or you're right.

For example you may have the following code:

```
class myClass():

    def myfunc(self):
        print(self.name)
```

PyCharm will probably complain that `self.name` can't be resolved. However, you may use the class like this:

```
my_class = myClass()
my_class.name = "Alastair"
my_class.myfunc()
```

which is perfectly valid (albeit brittle).

The message goes on to say that it's more confident about attribute and methods that are less ambiguous. For example:

```
class myClass():
    my_instance_var = "Al"

    def myfunc(self):
        print(self.my_instance_var)
```

As `my_instance_var` is defined in the source code (a class attribute), PyCharm can be confident it exists.

(Don't use class attributes unless you know what you're doing!)