# Stuck in Python official tutorial docs

Tags: python

> A piece of Python code that expects a particular abstract data type
> can often be passed a class that emulates the methods of that data
> type instead. For instance, if you have a function that formats some
> data from a file object, you can define a class with methods `read()`
> and `readline()` that get the data from a string buffer instead, and
> pass it as an argument.
>
> Instance method objects have attributes, too: `m.__self__` is the
> instance object with the method `m()`, and `m.__func__` is the
> function object corresponding to the method.

I am stuck at Python [tutorial doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends), I can't understand above docs. Can anyone explain it in a plain way?
with demo will be great. Some concept in python is very unfamiliar to me, I can't get the meaning of author.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What is dynamic dispatch and duck typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796813/what-is-dynamic-dispatch-and-duck-typing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A piece of Python code that expects a particular abstract data type can often be passed a class that emulates the methods of that data type instead. For instance, if you have a function that formats some data from a file object, you can define a class with methods read() and readline() that get the data from a string buffer instead, and pass it as an argument.

Consider something like this.

```
def get_first_line_twice(file):
    line = file.readline()
    return line + line
```

This is "A piece of Python code that expects a particular abstract data type". "a particular abstract data type" is, in this case, a file.

"a class that emulates the methods of that data type instead" means a class that also has a `readline()` method that behaves similarly. E.g.

```
class Foo:
    def readline(self):
        return "foo"
```

We can pass an instance of `Foo` instead of a file to our function, and it will work without errors. That's what the paragraph means.

> Instance method objects have attributes, too: m.__self__ is the instance object with the method m(), and m.__func__ is the function object corresponding to the method.

Consider the `Foo` class from previous example.

```
f = Foo()
f.readline #the method

f #"the instance object with the method"
f.readline.__self__ is f #True

f.readline.__func__ #"the function object corresponding to the method"
```

The last line essentially returns `readline` decoupled from `f`. If we want to call it, we will actually need to pass an object as the `self` parameter, i.e. `f.readline.__func__(f)`. Or `f.readline.__func__(some_other_object)`. This can be useful for advanced functional programming, or maybe reflection. As a beginner, you can ignore these attributes for now.